# Visual Studio Code can't find reference to SignInManager in .NET Core Project

Tags: .net-core

I'm getting an error when I try to reference SignInManager in one of my classes:

[image]

[image]

I have a "using" statement at the top of my class for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity, which is the library in which this class is found according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1?view=aspnetcore-1.0):

[image]

To make things even weirder, I also have a reference in this very same file to the UserManager class from the same library, and it is having no problem finding that!

[image]

I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple, but I am currently baffled. Any thoughts?

Comment: In my experience this could be an IDE bug. Had similar in Blazor. Usually clear and restore and IDE restart solves the issue for me.